# Function Call Variables Same as In Function

Tags: python, function, variables, return, call

I am somewhat new to Python--beginner moving to intermediate--and would like to know how more experienced Python coders name their call and function variables.

Specifically, I like to name the call variables the same as the called function's 'receive' variables. Ditto the return variables.

Works fine, but are there problems I could run into, outside of changing a variable to `global` in the future?

An example call: `v_Array = f_InitSpecified2DArray(v_Width,v_Length)`
The example called or 'receiving' function: `def f_InitSpecified2DArray(v_Width, v_Length):`
And I do the same in the return as well:  `return v_Array`

```
def f_InitSpecified2DArray(v_Width, v_Length):
    v_Array = [v_Width, v_Length]
    return v_Array

v_Array = f_InitSpecified2DArray(v_Width,v_Length)
```

The question is: Shall I expect any conflict resulting from reuse of name `v_Array` inside the function `return` and later in the calling code, where it goes assigned into variable with the same name `v_Array`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not cause you difficulties, and doesn't cause confusion - for you, your readers, or the Python interpreter. Certainly it's less confusing than making up a new name just to differ from the parameter name, which is unnecessary. In fact, you'll often encounter the same name being used for both a named parameter and its argument, as in

```
runner = DocTestRunner(verbose=verbose, optionflags=optionflags)
```

which comes from doctest.py in the standard library (for Python 3.3).

It's instructive to search the standard library for this pattern, `<name>=<same_name>` (abuse of notation which I'll rectify in a moment), as its occurrences are examples of just what you're asking about. On OS X and Linux, the following command will show all lines in the standard library (plus site-packages) with occurrences of the pattern:

```
grep -Er --include=*.py '(\b[[:alnum:]]+\b)=\1\b' /path/to/pythonlib
```

On a Mac, for example, `/path/to/pythonlib` for Python 3.3 is usually `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3`.

This command shows how many lines feature the construct, many of which have multiple occurrences:

```
grep -Er --include=*.py '(\b[[:alnum:]]+\b)=\1\b' /path/to/pythonlib | wc -l
```

I get a count of 1129, which includes a few dozen in my site-packages subdirectory. In other words, it's quite common.

Comment: You're welcome. Your question made me curious just how prevalent it is. Now we know - very :)

Comment: PS The 2nd `\b` in the grep regex is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Read [PEP 008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) titled "Style Guide for Python Code"

You seem to search for something more precise and systematic, this I appreciate, but you will safe a lot of effort and confusion to yourself and others dealing with your code, if you try to folow the PEP 008.

As usual, you will not find it followed everywhere, but that is life.

To your question about function names and variables - PEP 008 recommends using lowercase names with words separated by underscore.

local variable names are irrelevant, it really does not matter what variable name you use for `return`.

And do not plan moving variables into global scope too early, you shall in fact working in the other direction.

Comment: Jan, thanks for the reply. Being somewhat new, I had never heard of PEP 008. However, I am mostly curious on how people name their variables in their calls versus their functions in the 'wild', why and what pitfalls may lurk.

Comment: @Raw_Input I see your approach is very systematic. PEP 008 is summarizing answers to your questions. And you may also check source code of many python packagages - see pypi.python.org, pick some hosted on GitHub and review the code. Sample packages being e.g. requests, salt, Flask, Django, CherryPy .. thousands of them. You will find many diversions from PEP 008, but nobody is using the style you proposed.

Comment: Jan, I am not asking for feedback on my style of variable naming but if there may be a future problem with using the same names in function calls and within the functions themselves. Thanks.

Comment: @Raw_Input You are right, I did not read it carefully enough and in fact got stuck in the first paragraph of your question. I have edited your question with a piece of continuous code illustrating your question plus repeated your question at the end. I hope, I did understood it properly now.